# BitCoin GUI wallet which doesn't use much disk space

Tags: linux, gui, ubuntu, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I want a BitCoin GUI wallet which doesn't use much disk space.

bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/features/requirements says that Bitcoin Core uses 200GB. It is clearly too much. I would prefer to take no more than 2-3GB (or a little more), including any data (such as blockchain data) the program creates on the user PC.

It must be able to run on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: How much is "much disk space"? What's an average for some big/small wallets? (Where's 60GB come from?)

Comment: @Xen2050 https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/features/requirements says that Bitcoin Core uses 200GB. It is clearly too much. I would prefer to take no more than 2-3GB (or a little more)

Comment: Does your "2-3GB" include the stored blockchain data size?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, it includes any data the application creates on the user's PC

Comment: Thanks! Please add this information in the body of your question, I will delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Electrum.

From https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6huw0r/how_much_space_does_electrum_use/

1 mb or something below 10 mb for sure.

the reason bitcoin core is 60 gb or whatever it is is because you download the whole blockchain.

Comment: valid point about Electrum, but must keep in mind that it used to have some security vulnerabilities. however, this comment of mine is not very constructive, since I'm not able to suggest any other bitcoin client that fits the requirement and is more secure